# React-Native Animated in custom component

Tags: animation, react-native

I create a Custome Component With this prop:

`opacity: PropTypes.number, // opacity;`

In one page I use this to make it support animate.

`const AnimatedProgress = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(RecorderProgress);`

then , I set a opacity state.

`this.state= { _opacity: new Animated.Value(0)}`

and set a animate in componentDidMount;

`Animated.timing(this.state._opacity,{
      toValue:1,  // no-transparent;
      duration:5000
    }).start();`

add the component to page:

`<AnimatedProgress  opacity={opacity:this.state._opacity}/>`

But when I run the app, there is no animation of the component.

I also found that if I create a opacity in style of the component directly instead of giving it a opacity prop, the animation works.

`<AnimatedProgress  style={{opacity:this.state._opacity}}/>`

Please it's very confused me, is there any one who can help me?Thanks.